# Autoclick buttons in several tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, automation

I have about 10+ tabs open in my browser with each containing a button I need to click, in intervals of about 20-30 minutes.

I am looking for some kind of autoclick solution so that I don't have to go back to my browser every 20-30 minutes and manually click the button.

I downloaded an extension for Firefox called Autoclick but this didn't work. I'm thinking if there is maybe a better solution so that I can program these buttons in advance to be clicked in the interval I specify.

I am not sure here what the best solution would be. I'm wondering if anyone would have an idea.

I do not own this domain by the way so altering the source code of the form that needs to be sent is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can give Selenium a try. It can be installed as a plugin/extension in your browser.

[Selenium for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd) for example can record your actions and then playback them for you automatically.
Not sure about multiple tabs, but it should be possible.